# Convert a vector to two vectors of specific length

Tags: r

I have this vector:

```
 x <-c(0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 3.9, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9, 1.9, 0.5, 4.8,0.5, 0.9, .5, 5.9, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9, 2.9, 0.6, 3.8)
```

I would like to convert it to a sub two vectors each containing only `10` numbers.

The expected output I would like is something like this:

```
[1] 0.2 0.9 1.5 3.9 1.1 1.6 0.9 1.9 0.5 4.8    
[1] 0.5 0.9 0.5 5.9 1.1 1.6 0.9 2.9 0.6 3.8
```

Comment: `split(x, 0:(length(x)-1) %/% 10)`

Comment: @PoGibas could you please write it as answer so I will accept it. Also, could you please explain how I can access each element of each of them.

Comment: You could also use `gl` i.e. `split(x, as.integer(gl(length(x), 10, length(x))))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using `split()`:

```
x <- c(0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 3.9, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9, 1.9, 0.5, 4.8,0.5, 0.9, .5, 5.9, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9, 2.9, 0.6, 3.8)

lengthOfVector <- 10
res <- split(x, 0:(length(x) - 1) %/% lengthOfVector)
```

To access result you can use `res[[1]]`

```
[1] 0.2 0.9 1.5 3.9 1.1 1.6 0.9 1.9 0.5 4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> x1=x[seq(1,0.5*length(x))]
> x1
 [1] 0.2 0.9 1.5 3.9 1.1 1.6 0.9 1.9 0.5 4.8
> x2=x[seq(0.5*length(x),length(x))]
> x2
 [1] 4.8 0.5 0.9 0.5 5.9 1.1 1.6 0.9 2.9 0.6 3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that there is an easy way to do this task.

That is:

```
 x <-c(0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 3.9, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9, 1.9, 0.5, 4.8,0.5, 0.9, .5, 5.9, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9, 2.9, 0.6, 3.8)

x1 <- x[1:10]
x2 <- x[2:20]
```